# SoundPlayer and Windows 7 wav file

Tags: c#, audio, soundplayer

When I try to play the sound file "Windows Critical Stop.wav" I get the following exception: `exec  {"Sound API only supports playing PCM wave files."} System.Exception {System.InvalidOperationException}`

I understand what PCM is, I just do not know how to either: 1) play the sound file, 2) determine a priori that it is not PCM and will not play, and block the file from being chosen.

Here is the code I am using:

```
SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer();
player.SoundLocation = FileNameTextBox.Text;

try
{
    player.Play();
}
catch (Exception exec)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Sound could not be played: " + exec.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wave files can be encoded differently (even with the GSM codec), so just examine what codec is used to skip a particular one.  Just check the AudioFormat bits.

https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/

Comment: Thanks that helped.  The file in question had a 0x55 in that field.  For any curious I put in the following code:
if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
  BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.Open(dialog.FileName, FileMode.Open));
  br.BaseStream.Position = 20;
  Int16 aF = br.ReadInt16();
  br.Close();
  if ((aF != 1) && (aF != 2))
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Bad Audio format = " + audioFormat.ToString());
    return;

Another web site with format info:
http://www.sonicspot.com/guide/wavefiles.html
Had a bit more detail on formats.

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: This program can convert your files to PCM. Just uncheck the adware crap and it's free: http://www.nch.com.au/switch/

Answer (score -1):

You have to use this player the code you have is a system damager
Microsoft admin,